# How to uninstall GHCup and cabal after windows reinstallation

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, ghcup

Before reinstalling windows (both old and new are 10), I've run unins.exe file, but **C:\Haskell_Platform** folder was not deleted completely (**C:\Haskell_Platform\cabal** and **C:\Haskell_Platform\ghcup-gho30eys.v5c** 0.7 GB and 5.5 GB respectively) were still there. I thought that after windows installation they will be moved to windows.old folder, so I could delete them after, but they did not. So my question is may it possibly affect anything if I try to install HP again and if it is so, how to remove them properly?

Comment: AFAIK The Haskell platform is deprecated. I'd say if you want to uninstall just delete the folder.